# how to create maps by attributes with mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have documents that looks like that:

```
ref1:     5ec68d5edcf68a016c4d1f68
ref2:     5ec68d5edcf68a016c4d1f68
country:  "US"
date:     2020-05-22T00:00:00.000+00:00
hour:     14
time:     2020-05-22T14:42:11.396+00:00
type:     "x"
```

which I aggregate by type.
my desired outcome is something like:

```
ref1:    5ec68d5edcf68a016c4d1f68
ref2:    5ec68d5edcf68a016c4d1f68
date:    2020-05-22T00:00:00.000+00:00
contry: {
   US: {x: 1, y: 10 ...},
   CA: ....
   .
   .

},
hour: {
   14: {x: 5, y: 0 ...},
   20: ....
   .
   .

}
```

or alternatively to create a document for each 'attribute':

```
ref1:          5ec68d5edcf68a016c4d1f68
ref2:          5ec68d5edcf68a016c4d1f68
date:          2020-05-22T00:00:00.000+00:00
aggregatedBy:  'country'
res: {
   US: {x: 1, y: 10 ...},
   CA: ....
   .
   .

}
```

currently I have $group that aggregates only per ref1,ref2,date and looks like:

```
{
  _id: { date : '$date', ref1: '$ref1', ref2: '$ref2' },
  x: {
    $sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', 'x']}, 1, 0]}
  },
  y: {
    $sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$type', 'y']}, 1, 0]}
  },
}
```

I have no clue on how to apply that deeper level.